# CEF browser not execute script ! C#

Tags: c#, winforms, execute, chromium-embedded

I am trying to execute a script in CEF browser winforms C# solution, but it is not working.  I already tested the script with dev insepector chrome/Edge and it is working fine.  Is there anything I should do to make this work?

```
if (e.IsLoading) { return; }

try
{
    chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByClassName(\"button_content\")[0].click();;");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

}
```

Comment: from where do you call this method ? and what is the value of e.IsLoading during the call

Comment: if (e.IsLoading) { return; }

Comment: look, this one chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByClassName(\"button_content\")[0].click();;") works fine , check e.IsLoading, maybe it's true